# RabbitMQ negative acknowledgements does't work with PHP

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp

I create RabbitMQ listener:

```
$connection = new AMQPConnection(
    $AMQP_config['server'],
    $AMQP_config['port'],
    $AMQP_config['user'],
    $AMQP_config['password'],
    $AMQP_config['virtual_host']
);

$channel = $connection->channel();

$channel->basic_qos(
    null,
    1,
    null
);

$this->_query_start_time = time();

$channel->basic_consume(
    $AMQP_config['queue'],
    '',
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    array($this, 'CallbackResponse')
);

while(count($channel->callbacks)) {
    $channel->wait();
}

$channel->close();
$connection->close();
```

---

```
public function CallbackResponse(AMQPMessage $msg)
{
    $response = json_decode($msg->body)->acopMessage;

    if ($response->reqMRef == $this->_request_reference) {

        $msg->delivery_info['channel']->basic_ack($msg->delivery_info['delivery_tag']);

    } else {
        $msg->delivery_info['channel']->basic_nack($msg->delivery_info['delivery_tag'], false, true);
    }
}
```

I have 5 message in queue, but I always receive only one and then recursion started, because basic_nack doesn't work for message.

Whats wrong, why it's not work?

Using this: https://github.com/videlalvaro/php-amqplib

Comment: The problem resolve if I remove $channel->basic_qos(null, 1, null); But I still don't understand, why it's not work with basic_nack.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "recursion started". Your basic_qos line is telling RabbitMQ to send just one message at a time.

Comment: Yes, when I receive message from rabbit, I checked it, and if not mine message, I send basic_nack, but Rabbit dont send me next message.

Comment: I hope you know that when you set the third argument to true, it requeues the bad message giving the recursion you are talking about. You probably want to set a dead letter exchange and set that argument to false.